# bash script looping two functions

Tags: awk, sed, for

I would like to order the 5th column by highest value and select the 4th if it matches the 5th column.

cat TABLE_LIST

```
C1 C2  C3          C4                                          C5 C6
3  No  ENCRYPTION  /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/encryption.dbf  8  0  
2  No  RETENTION   /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/retention.dbf   5  0  
4  No  ORACLE      /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/oracle.dbf      2  0 
1  No  USERS       /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/users01.dbf     3  0`
```

It should look like this.

```bsh
for file in $C5; do
select $C4 from from dual;
done
```

```
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/users01.dbf from dual;
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/retention.dbf from dual;
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/oracle.dbf from dual;
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/encryption.dbf from dual;`
```

What I have tried so far is working but it read the output according to the value of C1, but I want to read according to C5, highest to lowest.

```bsh
for (( x=1; x <= ${FILE_COUNT}; x++)) ; do
        FILE_NAME=cat $TABLE_LIST|sort -rk5 |awk -vx="$x" '$1 == x {print $4} $3 == x {print $1}'
        FILE_SIZE=cat $TABLE_LIST|sort -rk5 |awk -vx="$x" '$1 == x {print $5} $3 == x {print $1}'
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what the output should be for the given input.

Comment: I just want to grab the values of column C4 order by C5 (highest to lowest).

Comment: Your sample output `select /opt/oracle...` lines aren't sorted by C5 descending...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484304/bash-script-looping-two-functions#comment887419_484304) you want to list the 4th column in the order dictated by the 5th column (in reverse numerical order).

```
$ sed '1d' <TABLE_LIST | sort -k5,5nr | awk '{ print $4 }'
/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/encryption.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/retention.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/users01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/oracle.dbf
```

The `sed` command strips the header from the file and the `sort` sorts the remaining lines on the 5th column in decreasing numerical order.  The final `awk` extracts the 4th column.

This would work as long as none of the columns contained a whitespace character within the column itself.

---

Would you want to insert those `select` and `from dual;` strings, then you could modify the `awk` part of the pipeline:

```
$ sed '1d' <TABLE_LIST | sort -k5,5nr | awk '{ printf("select %s from dual;\n", $4) }'
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/encryption.dbf from dual;
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/retention.dbf from dual;
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/users01.dbf from dual;
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/oracle.dbf from dual;
```

Comment: This is perfect!! Thanks a lot @kusalananda it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Awk > 4.0

```
gawk '
  FNR>1 {a[$5] = $4} 
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_desc"; 
    for (i in a) print "select " a[i] " from dual;"
  }
' TABLE_LIST 
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/encryption.dbf from dual;
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/retention.dbf from dual;
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/users01.dbf from dual;
select /opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/oracle.dbf from dual;
```